# Setting ACL Inheritance hangs using Powershell

Tags: powershell, inheritance, acl, powershell-4.0, ntfs

Looking for some assistance.  I have been tasked with re-enabling Inheritance for over 60TB of data.  I am using Powershell to accomplish this.  The issue I am running into is when the script runs, it queries the path to re-enable Inheritance and to also remove all explicit permissions and just leave the inherited ones.  The process starts and it just sits at one folder for a very long time.  More than 4 hours.  I am wondering if I am missing something.  Below is my script.  Need help.  Thank you

#Start Transcript
Start-Transcript -Path "D:\Temp\processlog_$(Get-Date -format MMM-dd-yyyy-hh-mm-ss-tt).log"

```
#Get Current Date
$Starttime = Get-Date -format "MMM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss: tt"

 #Imports NTFSSecurity Powershell Module
  Import-Module -Name NTFSSecurity -NoClobber

  #Setting File Path
  $errorlog = "D:\temp\error_$(Get-Date -format MMM-dd-yyyy-hh-mm-ss-tt).log"
  $dir = "\\path"

  Add-Content -Path $errorlog -Value "Inheritance Script Started $Starttime."

  $error.clear()
  Write-Host "Path Targeted $dir"
  Write-Progress -Activity "Inheritance Process" -Status "Please wait while files and folders are being      counted. This will take some time."

  $Path = Get-Childitem -Path $dir -Recurse 

 $TotalFiles = $Path.Count

$i = 0

foreach ($File in $Path) {
$i++
$PercentComplete = (($i / $TotalFiles) * 100)

Write-Progress -Activity "Inheritance Process $($_.name)" -Status "Setting Inheritance on File $i of   $($TotalFiles)" -PercentComplete $PercentComplete

$File | Enable-NTFSAccessInheritance -RemoveExplicitAccessRules

 #Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 5
}
Write-host "Total number of File and Folder items fixed:"$TotalFiles

Get-Item -Path $dir | Get-ACL| Enable-NTFSAccessInheritance -RemoveExplicitAccessRules

Clear-Variable -Name "Path"
$error | Out-File -FilePath $errorlog -Append -Encoding utf8 -NoClobber

$Endtime = Get-Date -format "MMM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss: tt"
Add-Content -Path $errorlog -Value "Inheritance Script Ended $Endtime."


#End Transcript
Stop-Transcript
```

I tried everything I can think of. Help

Comment: Have you stepped through this with a debugger such as Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Avoid doing it remotely. How large do you think the `$Path` variable will be? Maybe you should skip filling a variable and start piping it directly. What do you mean with `The process starts and it just sits at one folder` and how do you see that?

Comment: An-dir,  I am going to be working with 60tb+ of data.  The first part does a count of how many objects and then when goes to enable inheritance the process just sits there and does not move forward to the next object.

Comment: I have never seen `sitting` a script but maybe you can send a picture of the `chair` ;) - the size of the data should not matter. But how many files and folders you got to process. The first part doesn't simply count, it creates a very large variable that might be the chair it sits on because it is so fat ;) - simply directly pipe it - read that simple example https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/weekend-scripter-manage-ntfs-inheritance-and-use-privileges/

Comment: It stores about 30gb of data.  The issues is after it gets the total of items, when starts to set the inheritance, the process seems to be not doing anything and the progress bar shows what file or folder is currently working on. That is where I said it just sits there and does not move on.   I am the only person who is using the chair. :)